# Jetpack Compose: Update composable when list changes

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, android-jetpack-compose

I've got a composable on a Screen which shows a list of Track items (favourites) :

```
var favourites: MutableList<Track> by mutableStateOf(mutableListOf())
```

```
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Composable
private fun ResultList(model: FreezerModel) {
    with(model) {
        if (favourites.isEmpty()) NoDataMessage("No favourites yet")
        else {
            LazyColumn(state = rememberLazyListState()) {
                items(favourites) {
                    TrackCard(it, model)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On click events, I am updating my favourites list (add/remove item). How can I make my composable reflect these changes immediately (like to re-draw itself or something similar)? So far, it only works when I first switch to another screen.

Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: It should work with a `MutableStateList<T>`. Use var `favourites by mutableStateListOf<Track>()`

Comment: Thanks for your input! Is this also possible for a Set? I can't find any implementation...

Comment: Sets are not ordered and therefore do not implement `List<T>` nor `Array<T>` supported by `items()` and are therefore cannot be used as a parameter to `items()` directly. In this case, calling `toList()` on the set every time is updated would work.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to use a **`MutableStateList<T>`** so that Compose can automatically recompose when the state changes.

From [official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-other-types-of-state-in-jetpack-compose):

> Caution: Using mutable objects such as `ArrayList<T>` or `mutableListOf()` as state in Compose will cause your users to see incorrect or stale data in your app.

In your code use

```
val favourites = remember { mutableStateListOf<Track>()}
```

instead of

```
var favourites: MutableList<Track> by mutableStateOf(mutableListOf())
```

Comment: Awesome, thx again for your input!
Is this also possible for a Set? I can't find any implementation...

Comment: If I need list of list then?

Comment: In my case only `var canteens by mutableStateOf(mutableStateListOf<Canteen>())` works

Comment: What about `LivedData`  and `StateFlow`? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56658722/3466808.

Comment: We cannot use 'by' keyword with mutableStateListOf(). Use '=' symbol instead.

Comment: MutableStateList is no more available in Android

Comment: Drove an explanation to another query, and it's functioning nicely for my case. You can have a look at this explanation 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73706683/4676291

Comment: if MutableStateList is not available try mutableStateListOf instead, like mutableStateListOf<Card>() for instance.

Answer (score 10):

Just removing `state = rememberLazyListState()` from the `lazyColumnFor` params list should work in your case.

According to the doc if we use `rememberLazyListState()` then :-

> Changes to the provided initial values will **not** result in the state being recreated or changed in any way if it has already been created.

After doing so , normally *updating* the list should work fine. Also its a good practice to expose an immutable list ( `list` ) instead of a `mutableList` to the composable.

For example use:-

```
var favourites by mutableStateOf(listOf<FavoriteItem>())
```

then `add/remove/update` the list by using :-

```
favourites = favourites + newList // add 
favourites = favourites.toMutableList().also { it.remove(item) } // remove
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! Is this also possible for a Set? I can't find any implementation...

Comment: val setData = remember { mutableStateMapOf("1" to "Jayant","2" to "Manish") } 

    Text(text = "${setData["1"]}")

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `mutableStateMapOf()`, you can do like this

```
    val setData = remember { mutableStateMapOf("1" to "Jayant","2" to "Manish") }

    Text(text = "${setData["1"]}")
```

**Output**

```
Jayant
```