# (Android Studio) Jetpack Compose ArrayList<String> is resetting in ViewModel

Tags: android, arraylist, viewmodel, reset

This is a follow-up to my previous issue. I encountered another problem now where ArrayList variables, declared with the syntax by mutableStateOf(), in my ViewModel is resetting after being updated.

The ViewModel has a few mutableStateOf() variables, including Strings and the ArrayList. The String state variables keep the new values after being updated. Also, I am reassigning the ArrayList state variable to a new array each time, which I'm making sure of. The ArrayList is not simply having elements added/removed.

Quick example code where the issue is being experienced:

```
var heading by mutableStateOf("")
var titles by mutableStateOf(ArrayList<String>())

fun updateTitles(newTitleSet: ArrayList<String>){
    var newArray = ArrayList<String>()
    for (title in newTitleSet){
        newArray.add(title)
    }
    
    titles = newArray
}

fun changeHeading(newHeading: String){
    heading = newHeading
}
```

Calling the changeHeading function from a composable updates heading in ViewModel successfully. However, calling updateTitles results an issue where titles is first changed to the new ArrayList, but right after it is reverted to the default. I debugged the code where the fun updateTitles is called: by the end of the function execution, titles appears to be updated. However, when the function is called and executed again, the debugger shows that titles got reverted.

I don't know why this is occurring, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252538/jetpack-compose-update-composable-when-list-changes 
Check this app it will solve your problem

Comment: is title private or it has another setter outside the viewModel?

Comment: @Chirag Thummar Unfortunately, that link did not solve my problem. The problem isn't that the ui is not recomposing. It's that the ArrayList in the ViewModel appears to be updating after a function call, but then immediately resets.

Comment: @simon titles is not private, and there is no setter outside the vm.

Comment: I could suggest you to wrap your list and other variable in a single data class which I'm using in my project.